# Using a passphrase protected private key with crypto.createSign

Tags: node.js, cryptography, openssl

I'm trying to sign and verify a message using the node.js crypto API and a passphrase protected private key which gets me this:

```
> var sig = crypto.createSign('RSA-SHA256').update('psst').sign(pk,'hex');
Enter PEM pass phrase:
```

And node just locks up at this point. I can't seem to find an option to pass the passphrase in programatically.

Comment: What version of Node and OpenSSL are you using? I couldn't reproduce this problem on a Mac using OpenSSL 0.9.8l and the latest version of Node (v0.8.16).

Comment: I can reproduce using Node v0.10.18 with OpenSSL 0.9.8y 5 Feb 2013 on a Mac

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Update: I fixed this in core

My fix for this has just [landed in core](https://github.com/joyent/node/commit/f755ecf), <strike>it hasn't make an official release yet but when it does</strike> you can use it like so:

```
var sig = crypto.createSign('RSA-SHA256').update('psst').sign({
  key: pk,
  passphrase: 'password'
}, 'hex');
```

<strike>Will update once this lands in a release.</strike> Landed in v0.11.8 release.

### Original Answer:

Here's a solution that works, you can decrypt the private key when you app starts, and then use it normally, for example:

```
var  childProcess = require('child_process'),
  crypto = require('crypto');

var pk;

var sign = function () {
  var sig = crypto.createSign('RSA-SHA256').update('psst').sign(pk,'hex');
  console.log(sig);
};

childProcess.exec('openssl rsa -in /path/to/private_key -passin pass:your_password', {},
    function (err, stdout, stderr) {
  if (err) throw err;
  pk = stdout; // Save in memory for later use
  sign();
});
```

Comment: It gives me this error: 140735266955648:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:../deps/openssl/openssl/crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:703:Expecting: CERTIFICATE

Comment: Consider passing the password as an argument to the script, or setting it as an environment variable instead of hard coding it

Comment: @pshah Unfortunately I think this is due to an error in your key file, for testing try generating a new one with `ssh-keygen -t rsa`.
@Plato Is correct, there are a few ways of passing in the passphrase, you can specify an environment variable with `... -passin env:var_name`, full details here: http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/openssl.html#PASS_PHRASE_ARGUMENTS

Comment: I was getting the error mentioned when I was trying to call verify (and not sign), but it seems like an unrelated issue. I did verify the key and it has no errors.

Comment: @pshah Updated answer as it's now fixed in core

Comment: @ThomSeddon That's awesome! I'm glad you fixed it in the core, so other people don't have to workaround.

Comment: @ThomSeddon Did it make it to an official release yet? Perhaps v0.10.24?

Comment: It's in the v0.11 branch, landed in v0.11.8